# The name 'rotateInput' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

What I am trying to do is make an airplane pitching system to pitch up once it recieves vertical input.

PS: Please note that I am a noob/beginner and I'm not the best programmer ever so if I make an obvious mistake(
Which I probably
did), just know it is from a noob

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerControllerX : MonoBehaviour
{
private float rotateSpeed = 5f;
private float horizontalInput;
public float forwardInput;
void Start()
{
    
}

void Update()
{
    horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    rotateInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime;  
}
void LateUpdate()
{

    
    
    transform.Rotate(0, rotateInput ,0);

 }
}
```

all errors:

Assets/Scripts/playerController.cs(18,9): error CS0103: The name 'rotateInput' does not exist in the current context

Assets/Scripts/playerController.cs(25,29): error CS0103: The name 'rotateInput' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Where did you define `rotateInput`?

Comment: Bruh, I just realised, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'rotateInput' does not exist in the current context means that you haven't declared it.
Here's I think, what you're trying to do. I've modified it

```
private float rotateSpeed = 5f; 
private float playerInput; //declaration

void Update()
{
   playerInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical"); 
    // "Vertical" <---> x axis
   transform.Rotate(Vector3.right*rotateSpeed*playerInput); 
    // Vector3.right <--->direction
}
```

This allows you to rotate object on an axis in the direction specified.
But there are better ways to deal with rotation like Quaternions, Addtorque()
(depends on requirement) that you can research.

Comment: Why even have class fields for those dynamic variables though? Anyway they seem to be consumed only at the place where they are also assigned -> simply use a local variable